# Is 1Thess 1:10 a piece of early christian poetry?

Tags: greek, 1-thessalonians, poetry

I was reading a peroratio of 1Thess (5:16-22) recently and I had some feeling of rhytmicity there. After closer look the issue seems to be not so simple so I gave up with it for a moment.

However in 1Thess is another place (1:10) which is usually considered as some form of credo maybe originally deriving from an early christian hymn or something like that. I have no doubt that there is indeed kind of rhytm at least in syntax and selection of words (see markered words and phrases). But maybe there is something more? I have read it by loud and noticed some metre. So I wrote down what I have heard and - maybe I'm naive, but - there could be a real metric structure if we will use some exceptions of rules (for example when we will recognize a short vowel as long before liquida). Maybe it's a verdant's figment, but I'm excited :D

I enclose a simple scheme of metre below (it might contain a few mistakes - as I said - I'm a beginner).

What do you think about this? Have you heard abut any article or lecture which correspond with the subject? Unfortunatelly none of commentaries on 1Thess refer to this in more comprehensive way.

[image]

Comment: There are a few things in your scansion I don't understand. In the first line, for example, I would think the second syllable of υιον should be short (before a vowel), εκ should be long (before a consonant), the first syllable of ουρανων should be long. You seem to be trying to scan this as dactylic meter, but it seems to me that this is possibly more similar to (loose) iambic meter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding "υιον" I suppose you mean the first syllabe - υι should indeed be short before a vowel, but I don't remember if it's an unavoidable rule or only possibility. Whereas -ον normally should be short, I considered it as long because of the rule I have mentioned - vowel before liquid consonant is capable of changing it's lenght. The same apply to first syllabe of ουρανων. In following comment I will copy a scheme without using any exceptions, maybe it would be helpful.

Comment: 1: u u u – u – – – – – 
2: u – – u – – – – 
3: u – – – u u u u (– –) II – – – – – – u u –
I think there is way too many long syllabes in a row to form any serious iambic meter. This is why I considered it as dactylic and looked for spondees there.

Comment: The first syllable of υιον is long; a diphthong is only short before another vowel across word boundaries. ον isn't before a liquid; it's before a vowel, so it must be short. I am not an expert, but I have never encountered the rule you say about a long vowel becoming short before a liquid. Iambic meter can have multiple long vowels in a row, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_trimeter

Comment: Ah, I was wrong - in the rule which I mentioned vowel can (or not) change lenght before muta cum liquida, not liquida alone. So I need to reconsider an entire thing. Thanks for help.

Comment: If you ever revisit the question you might want to ask on [Latin Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) which also accepts questions about Greek, since people who focus on classical Greek probably know more about prosody

Answer (score -1):

There is a definite poetic structure to the verse as you parsed it. I cut and pasted the Greek of the verse [into Google Translate and listened to it](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%CE%BA%CE%B1%E1%BD%B6%20%E1%BC%80%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%BC%E1%BD%B3%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BD%20%CF%84%E1%BD%B8%CE%BD%20%CF%85%E1%BC%B1%E1%BD%B8%CE%BD%20%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%20%E1%BC%90%CE%BA%20%CF%84%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD%20%CE%BF%E1%BD%90%CF%81%CE%B1%CE%BD%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD%20%E1%BD%83%CE%BD%20%E1%BC%A4%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%BD%20%E1%BC%90%CE%BA%20%CF%84%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD%20%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%81%E1%BF%B6%CE%BD%20%E1%BC%B8%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%CE%BD%20%CF%84%E1%BD%B8%CE%BD%20%E1%BF%A5%CF%85%E1%BD%B9%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%E1%BC%A1%CE%BC%E1%BE%B6%CF%82%20%E1%BC%90%CE%BA%20%CF%84%E1%BF%86%CF%82%20%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CE%B3%E1%BF%86%CF%82%20%CF%84%E1%BF%86%CF%82%20%E1%BC%90%CF%81%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BC%E1%BD%B3%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%82). It was read in modern Greek manner, which apparently is sing-songy, or maybe that's the software, but there seemed to be a rhythm and rhyme. I wouldn't die on that hill or anything but the structure is apparent to me.